# Keyboard layout indicator doesn't change after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 22.04

Subj. I've used Gnome Tweaks to set switch method to `ctrl+shift`. Everything worked great until I upgraded Ubuntu. After the upgrade the layout does change but the indicator doesn't represent the actual layout. E.g. if it shows **en** by the time system loaded, it will remain **en** regardless the layout I actually switched to. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: It's [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916).

Comment: During login select a session that is not Wayland.

Comment: Thanks @FedKad, selecting Ubuntu on x.org did the trick

Comment: I've the same issue, but here I don't understand how to solve.

Comment: @SirJoBlack when you on login screen, you can find a session type selector in the bottom right corner